# How can I change the font size of a Thunderbird thread list on a Mac?

Tags: macos, thunderbird

How do I change the font size of a Thunderbird thread list on a Mac?

I don't see any settings in the preferences.

Comment: Set it up 11 intead and it will display better

Answer (score 5):

[Daniel's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/175135/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-a-thunderbird-thread-list-on-a-mac/227622#227622) is correct. You have to extend `userChrome.css` in the `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/[yourProfileName]/chrome/` folder. Here is the CSS code that will fix the spacing as well:

```
/* Set default namespace to XUL */
@namespace
url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

/* Set font size in folder pane */
#folderTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text {
    font-size: 12pt !important;
}

/* Set font size in thread pane */
#threadTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text {
    font-size: 12pt !important;
}

/* Set height for cells in folder pane */
#folderTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
   height: 25px !important;
}

/* Set height for cells in thread pane */
#threadTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
   height: 25px !important;
}
```

Thunderbird versions `> 115.*` have changed the styling, this works for me:

```
/* Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning */
/* set default namespace to XUL */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
@namespace html url("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

/* Set Font Size And Spacing In Folder Pane */

html|ul#folderTree html|li[is="folder-tree-row"] > html|div.container > html|span.name {
    font-size: 1.45rem !important;
    line-height: 1.6 !important;
}

/* Set Font Size And Spacing In Thread Pane */

html|table[is="tree-view-table"] {
    font-size: 1.45rem !important;
    line-height: 1.65 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is a proper stylesheet but the crucial point is to switch on `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` as @Nicolai wrote in his answer: https://superuser.com/a/1678560/534153

Answer (score 2):

You need to [edit your userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Pane_and_menu_fonts) file.

Go to `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/[yourProfileName]/chrome/` (creating the `chrome` directory if it doesn't exist) and edit `userChrome.css`, again creating if it doesn't exist.

For example, to edit all text in Thunderbird (except message view), enter the following:

```
/* Global UI font */
*
{
    font-size: 18pt !important;
    font-family: Verdana !important;
}
```

The result looks something like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I was unable to find the CSS class for the message list. Replace the `*` in the CSS content with that CSS class, and it should work as intended.

Comment: Yes, this example is exaggerated, but how else can I prove it works?

Comment: This solution only helps a little bit, because you only increase the font - but you need to add space for that larger font as well.

Comment: Alternatively, let Thunderbird open the profile folder. In some versions, menu *Help* → *Troubleshooting Information* → *Open Directory* (near *"Profile Directory"*).

Answer (score 2):

[qingu has most of the correct answer](https://superuser.com/a/667092/1550764), i.e. you need to create a ~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles//chrome/userChrome.css file containing

```
/* Set default namespace to XUL */ @namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

/* Set font size in folder pane */
#folderTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text {
    font-size: 10pt !important; }

/* Set font size in thread pane */
#threadTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text {
    font-size: 10pt !important; }

/* Set height for cells in folder pane */
#folderTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
    height: 20px !important; } /* Set height for cells in thread pane */
#threadTree >treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
    height: 20px !important; }
```

You also must go to the Thunderbird Preferences->Config Editor (last option in the preferences), search for the value `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
and toggle it to True. Without this, the CSS customisation will not be read.

The default size seems to be about 6pt, so 10pt makes it significantly more readable (on a Retina display). The example above also adjusts the height of each row in the message list to match a 10pt font size.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a folder named `chrome` in the profile folder. On a Mac it is located in `/users/NAMEOFTHEUSER/Libraries/Thunderbird/Profiles/NAMEOFTHEPROFILE/` and there you need to make a new text file named `userChrome.css`, as discussed in the previous answers.

```
listitem, treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
    min-height: 2em !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain where the user is meant to enter this code and what it will do?

Comment: You have to make a folder named "chrome" in the profile folder. On a Mac it is located in /users/NAMEOFTHEUSER/Libraries/Thunderbird/Profiles/NAMEOFTHEPROFILE/  and there You need to make a new text file named userChrome.css. Just like the previous answers told

Comment: I suggest you have a read of [How to write a good answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). It will explain how SuperUser works and hopefully in future prevent you from having answers deleted or from receiving downvotes.

Comment: Alternatively, let Thunderbird open the profile folder. In some versions, menu *Help* → *Troubleshooting Information* → *Open Directory* (near *"Profile Directory"*).

Answer (score 0):

I use the "Theme Font & Size Changer" add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/theme-font-size-changer/

This add-on gives you a little GUI, where you can easily change the font-size of the thread-list (and the tree), without fiddling around in the css file.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just/at least a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I have found is described in this thread:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1297871
Might not be perfect but it works at least for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1127562)