# Thunderbird "Folders" and "Inbox" font size

Tags: windows-7, fonts, thunderbird

Graphical programs are such a pain sometimes. I am of an age where 1024x768 is the highest resolution that I can see. I had set my Windows 7 system fonts to be 125% - that helps a lot - but it screws up the tool bars on many other programs so I've reverted to 100% and it's now too hard to read in many cases.

Most browsers will let you easily scale text font size as will the "message" window of Thunderbird (aside from setting the default font size for reading messages to 24 point, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> works wonders). However, I cannot seem to find a way to set the font size for the other panes - the Folders pane and the inbox pane.

Is there some undocumented way to do that?

Comment: Related: *[How can I change the font size of a Thunderbird thread list on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/175135)*

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can customize the CSS of the UI by editing the useChrome.css file.

More on that topic here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css

Comment: Do you happen to know if this should still work? I tried it in Thunderbird 60 and userChrome.css with contents `@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); *{font-size:72pt !important;}` has no effect on anything whatsoever, tested in Windows 10 and Debian Stretch.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me today on Firefox or Thunderbird:

1. In Firefox: go to about:config; in Thunderbird: click on the Config editor in the General Settings
2. Set the field layout.css.devPixelsPerPx to the adequate scale factor (1.25, for instance)
3. In Thunderbird, set also the field mail.uifontsize (to 12, for instance)