# Setting the font size in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm having trouble trying to change the font size in Thunderbird. I can see that I can change it to "larger font size", or "smaller font size", but how can you set it as a number, say "12px" or "12pt"?

[image: Thunderbird font settings]

Comment: Related: *[How can I change the font size of a Thunderbird thread list on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/175135)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of looking around I've found what seems to be causing the problem. Thunderbird HTML emails use the `<font></font>` in which the size is set using `<font size="2">`, so when you click size up / down it changes the size attribute which is not a set number rather a scale.